# Difference between 2 dates en JS

Tags: javascript, date

I've this:

```
<script>    
  var a = '2013-09-07';
  var b = '2013-09-15';
</script>
```

I want to have the difference in `days` between these two dates.

I have tried this:

```
var a = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var b = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var oneday = 86400000;
alert((b-a) / oneday);
```

But I have a NaN alert().

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:-

```
var date1 = new Date("09/07/2013");
var date2 = new Date("09/15/2015");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JS69L/48/)

Comment: And if you do more date stuff, look into [momentjs](http://momentjs.com)! A small library that does this, and more!

Comment: @stevuu:- Yes I was about to add that!!! :)